# Initializing several values of a function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, assignment

How do I initialize several values of a function at once? Consider the function

```
f[0] := 1;
f[1] := 2;
f[2] := 3;
f[n_] := f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-2] + f[n-3];
```

Is there a way to specify the initial conditions compactly? I would like to do something like

```
f[[{0,1,2}]] := {1,2,3}
```

but couldn't find the correct syntax in Mathematica.

Comment: `MapThread[(f[#]:= #2) &, {{0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}]`

Answer (score 7):

Some version of the following might be useful:

```
ClearAll[f];
Evaluate@Thread[f[{0, 1, 2}]] := {1, 2, 3};
```

In this case you could also use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`), because the arguments are "atomic", not patterns. Both `=` and `:=` hold their first argument unevaluated by default, so that a construct like `Thread` as I am using it above will only work in conjunction with `Evaluate` to force the left-hand side to evaluate, leading to the intermediate result `{f[0],f[1],f[2]}`, to which we then assign the list of values `{1, 2, 3}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map[(f[# - 1] := #) &, Range[3]];
f[n_] := f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-2] + f[n-3];
```

Or alternatively:

```
(f[#-1]:= #)&/@Range[3];
f[n_] := f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-2] + f[n-3];
```

Just in one line:

```
f[n_] := If[MemberQ[Range[0, 2], n], n + 1, f[n - 1] + f[n - 2] + f[n - 3]];
```